# How to split Tmux vertically and choose the size of the pane

Tags: linux, tmux

I am trying to 'auto split' Tmux with a **sh** file where I specify what panes I want and the size (width or height depending on the split direction). Horizontally works fine, but vertically doesn't.
the file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux new-session -d 'vim'
tmux split-window -h -p 25 # <== This is the one that doesn't work
tmux split-window -v -p 40 'rails server' # <== This does work
tmux split-window -v -p 30 'bin/webpack-dev-server' # This also does
tmux attach-session -d
```

I attach a screnshot for being clearer.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw02J.png

Comment: What is wrong exactly? You're saying "horizontally works fine, but vertically doesn't", then `-h` "doesn't work" and `-v` "does work". But in `man tmux` `-h` is called "horizontal split" (and in my OS this creates panes side by side), `-v` is called "vertical split" (one pane on top of the other). Therefore I'm not sure which one allegedly "doesn't work" for you. The only unexpected thing in your screenshot is the left pane being active (I would expect bottom right). Percentages don't match because you didn't use `-x`, `-y` with `new-session`; then `attach-session` resized the whole session.